# Set Label Content vertical Center in ItemsControl

Tags: wpf

Got this XAML for my Data Binded Label:

```
<ItemsControl 
    Name="itClblArtiksel" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ArtikelInfo}" 
    Margin="925,45,0,0" 
    Width="89" 
    Height="31"  
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    BorderThickness="1" 
    BorderBrush="Black"  
    FontWeight="Bold"
    >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label  
                x:Name="lblArtikelNr" 
                Content="{Binding ArtNr}" 
                />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

i already tried to set the `VerticalContentAlignment` of the `ItemsControl and Label`  to `Center` but the content dont get centered... any ideas?

**EDIT**

Picture to demonstrate the situation:
[image]

as you can see the bold one (so the one with `<itemcontrol>`) are in the air

**EDIT 2**

The accepted answer gave me the final solution:

```
<ItemsControl Name="itClblArtiksel" ItemsSource="{Binding ArtikelInfo}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="37"  Margin="925,45,236,38" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"  FontWeight="Bold">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Height="37">
                                    <Label  
                                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        x:Name="lblArtikelNr" 
                                        Content="{Binding ArtNr}" 
                                       />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
```

setting a `Grid` around the `Label` with the same `Height` as the `ItemsControl`and setting then the `VerticalAlignment` to `Center` was the workaround.

Comment: use snoop or wpf inspector to analyse your gui; but i think you must add a container like a grid arround your label that will fill the list item

Comment: Your ItemsControl has a fixed Height of 31. How do you intend to center anything vertically when the control is no taller than the labels themselves?

Comment: Try and go back to basics, remove margins, sizes etc and then try and add one thing at a time at notice how the UI changes. It can get messy and hard to see whats wrong with XAML sometimes. Also, add background colors to debug and visualize the extent of your controls to better understand how they fill up the space.

Comment: Removed Height,no success

Comment: Maybee what you are missing is a <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle> to set alignment of the item containers to fill up all available space? That's a common issue with ItemsControl.

Comment: @AndreasZita alread tried to set itemcontainerstyle from a other solution on stackoverflow, no success

Comment: Can you describe more in detail what you are after? I'm not sure I understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will center the labels vertically within their parents. In your case, this will have *no effect* because the items are only as tall as their content.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Label  
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        x:Name="lblArtikelNr" 
        Content="{Binding ArtNr}" 
        />

</DataTemplate>
```

If you want them to be visibly centered vertically, you need to give them room for that to happen:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid Height="100">
        <Label  
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            x:Name="lblArtikelNr" 
            Content="{Binding ArtNr}" 
            />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

But since your `ItemsControl` has a fixed height of 31, this will simply make the items larger than their parent, pushing the label out of sight. You need to remove that. I also urge you to consider getting accustomed to using `StackPanel` and `Grid` for layout, rather than setting very large margins on everything. The margins method makes it hard to rearrange your UI.

Answer (score 1):

How about setting the `VerticalAlignment` property of the `Label` to `Center`?

```
<Label x:Name="lblArtikelNr" Content="{Binding ArtNr}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

Comment: It works for me. Can you provide a picture that demonstrates the result you are seing and the expected ones?

Comment: What's the difference between the accepted answer and setting the VerticalAlignment to Center?

Comment: first sorry for the delay, i will just edit my answer to show you

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<ItemsControl 
  BorderThickness="1" 
  BorderBrush="Black"  
  FontWeight="Bold">
  <ItemsControl.Items>
    <system:String>wefwefwefwe</system:String>
    <system:String>wefwefwefwe</system:String>
    <system:String>wefwefwefwe</system:String>
    <system:String>wefwefwefwe</system:String>
  </ItemsControl.Items>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:String}">
      <Label Height="50" Foreground="Black" Content="{Binding}" BorderThickness="1"
             BorderBrush="Black" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

[image]